# Problems installing python2.7 package pyhsmm on 64 bit windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, gcc, package, cython

I've having difficulty installing this python 2.7 package [pyhsmm](https://github.com/mattjj/pyhsmm) on 64 bit Windows.  It is known to work on OS.X 10.8 and Arch Linux with Anaconda and I am attempting a Windows x64 install with the Python distribution Anaconda-2.0.1-Windows-x86_64. This Anaconda distribution uses MingW 4.7.0. Pyhsmm uses Cython to generate c++ code for the package.  There is a problem during gcc linking about undefined symbols that looks like this:

`D:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\util\cstats.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\util\cstats.def -LD:\Anaconda\libs -LD:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o D:\Python\packages\pyhsmm\pyhsmm\util\cstats.pyd
Cannot export cstats: symbol not defined`

A fuller account of attempts to install this can be found [here](https://github.com/mattjj/pyhsmm/issues/27).

Any insights or help, perhaps drawing on python on windows/cython/gcc your experience would be most appreciated.